# Pass json into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file like this

```
[{"excursionDay":"2"},{"excursionDay":"3"},{"excursionDay":"4"}]
```

I want to pass the value of excursionDay into an array in javascript like this

```
  dayValues = [2,3,4]
```

My javascript code so far is the following

```
fucntion excursionDates(date){
var day = date.getDay();
   var dayValues = [];
   $.get('json.php',function(data){
       for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
           dayValues.push(data[i].excursionDay);
       }
   },'json');
 }
```

But for some reason i can't get this work.
All of the above i want to triggered when i click in a jquery-ui datepicker and enable only the specific days. The code for the datepicker is bollow.

```
$("#excursionDate").datepicker({
        minDate: today,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: excursionDates
});
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: You including jquery?

Comment: Take a look: `jQuery.map` ... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: It working fine check http://jsfiddle.net/L4s645v2/

Comment: My console result is [2,3,4] but 28 times cause i am trying to return those values into a jquery-ui calendar to enable only specific days.

Comment: See my answer, try beforeShow(), it won't iterate as beforeShowDay.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code looks in order, but I'm suspecting that you're not responding with `application/json`, but with `text/html`.

Make sure you're doing the following in json.php.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
data.forEach( function(element){
   dayValues.push(element.excursionDay);
})

console.log(dayValues); // outputs ["2", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect use case for Array.map:

```
var startArray = [{"excursionDay":"2"},{"excursionDay":"3"},{"excursionDay":"4"}];

var dayValues = startArray.map(function(item){
                    return item.excursionDay
                });

//dayValues is now ["2","3","4"]
```

[More info on Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Hay i advise you to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

the method

```
_.values(object)
```

it returns all the values of the object in an array.

```
_.values({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
result: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily in JavaScript:

```
var jsArray = [];
var p = [{"excursionDay":"2"},{"excursionDay":"3"},{"excursionDay":"4"}];
for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    jsArray.push(p[i].excursionDay);
}

console.log(jsArray);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VaMoose/8TT4p/440/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** - Use **[.push()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)** for insert record into `array`

```js
var dataArray=[{"excursionDay":"2"},{"excursionDay":"3"},{"excursionDay":"4"}];
dayValuesArray = [];
 for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length;i++){
        dayValuesArray.push(dataArray[i].excursionDay);
    }
alert(dayValuesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
var jsonString ='[{"excursionDay":"2"},{"excursionDay":"3"},"excursionDay":"4"}]';

var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);    
var dayValues = [];
for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++){
    dayValues.push(obj[i].excursionDay);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

**The array part of your code should work fine. But the datepicker call is not.**

I guess you should use `.beforeShow()` method (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow), it would work better than `.beforeShowDay()` that will iterate before each day.

```
$("#excursionDate").datepicker({
        minDate: today,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShow: excursionDates
});
```